# Ag Grid version 28.2.1 | How to fill a cell | Overwrite Cell Padding to 0px

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Using a custom CellRenderer, I am trying to fill the cell - at whatever its present size is. As such, the cell renderer returns a component like so:

```
(params) => (<div style={{width: "100%", height: "100%", backgroundColor: "yellow"}} />)
```

However, the div doesn't show up since the ag-cell-wrapper div doesn't have any set size. To get around this I tried adjusting the scss file like so:

```
@use "~ag-grid-community/styles" as ag;

@include ag.grid-styles((
    theme: xxx,
    extend-theme: balham,
    --ag-cell-horizontal-padding: 0px, /* doesn't appear to do anything */
));

.ag-theme-xxx {
  .ag-cell {
    padding: 0px; /* doesn't appear to do anything */
  }

  .ag-cell-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .ag-cell-value {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

  }
}
```

While this gets me most of the way there, the left and right paddings for an ag-cell are still being hard-coded to 11px. How can I overwrite the cell padding to 0px?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following scss configuration works for me. That said, I prefer not having to use !important - so I'll leave this question open for the time being in case anyone can find a solution that works better with AgGrid than forcibly overriding their css.

```
@use "~ag-grid-community/styles" as ag;

@include ag.grid-styles((
    theme: xxx,
    extend-theme: balham
));

.ag-theme-xxx {
  .ag-cell {
    padding: 0px !important;
  };

  .ag-cell-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  };

  .ag-cell-value {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  };
};
```